# Logstash use JSON field date instead of @timestamp

Tags: json, timestamp, logstash

I'm facing this issue.
I'm trying to use custom JSON log date as my "usable" date instead of the @timestamp date field.

My JSON file to be processed by Logstash (comming from filebeat):

```
{
    "start":    {
       "timestamp": {
            "time": "Wed, 04 Apr 2018 09:36:39 GMT",
            "timesecs": 1522834599
        }
    }
}
```

My logstash.yml file :

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 1337
    codec => "json_lines"
  }
}

filter {
   date {
      match => [ "time", "EEE, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ" ]
   }
}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "testing"
  }
}
```

Also tried to :

```
match => [ "[start][timestamp][time]", "EEE, dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ" ]
```

Still no luck.

Any help would be welcome.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `match` the date using `date` filter, it stores the matching timestamp into the given [target](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-target) field. If `target` not provided, it will simply update the `@timestamp` field of the event with the new matching `time`.

> **target**
>
> Store the matching timestamp into the given target field. If not
>   provided, default to updating the @timestamp field of the event.

`target` will automatically create a field if it doesn't exists.

So following code is enough,

```
date {
     match => [ "[start][timestamp][time]", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z" ]
     target => "newTimeField"
     locale => "en"
     remove_field => [ "[start][timestamp][time]" ]  
}
```

`remove_field` above is another common option available for `date` filter. It is used to delete `[start][timestamp][time]` field once its stored in a new field.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did it - thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Got to the solution like this :

```
mutate {
     add_field => {
             "mytime" => ""
     }
}

date {
     match => [ "[start][timestamp][time]", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z" ]
     target => "mytime"
     locale => "en"
}
```